# Which version of marionette_driver with Firefox 52.9.0esr (Tor Browser 7.5.6)

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

The Tor Browser updated to 7.5.6. The previously working code failed with

> InvalidSessionIdException:

After updating to `marionette_driver 2.7`, the call to `client.start_session()` failed with

> marionette_driver.errors.UnknownCommandException: WebDriver:NewSession

Which version of the `marionette_driver` should be used with this Firefox version? (Or maybe another framework like Selenium?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are [only a few version at Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/marionette_driver/#history), and no other answer seems to exist, just try them all starting with the current one.

It worked with version 2.5:

```
pip2 install marionette_driver==2.5
```

---

UPDATE: The `InvalidSessionIdException` returned. To fix this, call `client.start_session()` again (it can be called when catching the exception in a `try`-block)